# React Native/Firebase App - want countdown functionality to cease if user exits app

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have built a react native app/game where a user has 30 mins to finish a task....when they start task, the 30 mins starts to countdown and it is registered in DB (Firebase) that user is "in play".  When they complete task (or 30 mins run out) then DB is again updated to "not in play".
Countdown function is operating on phone and not on server.

Problem is that if the user exits the app, then the counter on the phone ceases (the user is no longer "in play") but the DB does not know about it.....there appears to be no "user has exited app" event/handler that I can use to let DB know that user has quit.

I was thinking maybe the countdown logic should be running on backend but I cant think how.....any ideas?

Comment: you can add exit app handle method, when the user exit, reset the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to detect that the user has left the game would be with Firebase's [`onDisconnect` handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-presence). With this call you register a write operation on the database that is executed when the server detects that the client is gone.

The server can detect this in two ways:

1. If the client disconnects cleanly, it sends a message to the server that it is disconnecting and the server runs the disconnect handlers for that client straight away.
2. If the client disconnects in another way, the server will detect that the client is gone when the socket times out, which may take a few minutes.

So in your case you could use an `onDisconnect` handler to either remove the player from the game, or otherwise mark them as "gone".

The only problem with this approach is that dirty disconnects may take a few minutes, which might be too long for your scenario.

---

An alternative would be to have the client write a message into the database periodically to signify that it's still here, e.g. a `lastUpdated` timestamp.

You can then in any code that *reads* the data use that timestamp to detect if the player was still recently playing, and consider them "gone" after a certain period that works well for your game. This code can then remove the player from the database.

This code can run in a server-side component if you want, but I've in the past also run this type of code in the client and then used (server-side) security rules to ensure it can only remove users that are "gone".

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to handle app terminated in React Native so I think your best shot is to implement it on the backend.

How about when the user starts, you save the time the user started, and if the time difference between now and when the countdown was started surpasses 30 minutes the user is no longer "in play".